# How to set name for received emails in s3 with amazon ses

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ses

I checked SES developer guide, in the example when an email is stored in S3, it is named with a random ID. But I would like to set the name to the recipient email address. Is there a way to do it? Do I have to use Lambda?

Comment: What about situations where there is more than one email for that recipient?

Comment: For my use case I am only expecting to receive 1 email per recipient, and will delete it after reading

Answer (score 0):

You could configure an Amazon S3 Event to trigger an AWS Lambda function whenever Amazon SES stores an email in the Amazon S3 bucket.

The Lambda function would need to:

- Extract the Bucket and Key from the `event` data passed to the function
- Read the S3 object to obtain the recipient email address
- Copy the S3 object to a new name (Key) based on the recipient email address
- Delete the original S3 object

The above method would overwrite any existing object with the same name.

Comment: Cool, that's what I am doing now, seems the Lambda function is inevitable in this case. Thanks!

Comment: why not forward to lambda straight away since SES seems to allow that scenario.